# Is there any way to totally disable notification channel features in Android O?

Tags: android

For example, if I open the notification channel settings for the **Phone** app in Android O and select the **Incoming calls** category, I can see that the **Importance**, **Sound** and **Vibrate** options are totally disabled (i.e. greyed out), so that the user cannot modify anything about them.

If I need to do this in my app, how can I do it?

Comment: I doubt that it is possible for ordinary apps.

Comment: @CommonsWare You're right, I doubt it too. Anyway, I'm trying to explore all possible options. Some apps are having a hard time adapting some features to notification channels.